# How to get specific content from a remote json array with PHP

Tags: php, json

I need a way to display specific content from a remote json array. I tried something that you would do with a MySQL array but that didn't seem to work. My current code it something like this (without the curl settings and stuff):

```
$epf = json_decode(curl_exec($down));
$type = $epf['type'];
echo $type;
```

Can anyone give me a simple solution of how get content from a specific heading, such as 'cost'?

Comment: Please tell that what is your data/content? what you did(your code)? What is the error you are facing? So that we can tell some thing better to you. Yes as @zerkms said, var_dump your data and tell the output you are having in $epf so that we can know that what is in your $epf.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather use `print_r($epf);`

Comment: he need to show some specific element in json, while print_r prints whole array

Comment: I try to give the hint to discover the structure of the JSON response, so he can later extract the part he wants. He seems to have trouble finding the right key for the array.

Comment: yah may be, but it can be nested also, so I think var_dump can be better to see response more clearly

Comment: `print_r()` __also__ shows the nesting parts. The only difference is that `var_dump()` includes type and length. For rapid discover, I tend to prefer `print_r()`, but that is a matter of tastes...